# Map Transformation to Force Convergence to Unique Fixed Point

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Is there a transformation $\mathcal{T}$ of maps $\mathbb{R}_{{\geq}0}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{{\geq}0}^{n}$ with the following property?

> If a map $F : \mathbb{R}_{{\geq}0}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{{\geq}0}^{n}$ is smooth and order-reversing with respect to the product order and possesses a unique fixed point $\omega$, then
>
> - The point $\omega$ is the unique fixed point of ${\mathcal{T}}\!F$; and
> - For some (known) point $a \in \mathbb{R}_{{\geq}0}^{n}$, the sequence of iterates of ${\mathcal{T}}\!F$ starting at $a$ converges to the (unknown) point $\omega$.

For more on this question, please refer to the 3-page PDF document at this address: http://math.gillesgnacadja.info/files/FixedPointAlgo_OPEN.html. I would have liked to post everything here but I could not find a way to save and preview the question before posting it. The content of the document is as follows.

1. The Question
2. Why this Question?
3. The Trivial Case $n = 1$
4. Where Does This Question Come From?
5. Satisfying the Hypotheses of the Question
6. An Analogous Question

Comment: What do you mean by "order-reversing" if $n>1$?

Comment: My guess is the product order, although it might be lexicographic order.

Comment: Thanks to fedja for the question and to Ricky Demer for the answer. The order is indeed the product order. I added the precision in the question.